# Can I split a disk image and run Photorec on each part individually?

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, disk-image, testdisk

I'm running [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on an external HD connected via USB and it's taking too long, with the estimated remaining time constantly increasing.

Is there a way to create a disk image from that external drive, split it in smaller parts, copy each part to my internal SSD (one at a time) and run Photorec on it? I don't have much free space on the SSD, so I can't have the entire image copied at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but if any file crosses the split boundary, you won't be able to recover it. Of course, you could go for overlapping splits to avoid that problem (overlap size being at least the maximum file size you're expecting to recover). However, it's questionable at best whether you would actually see the desired speed increase.

Suppose you want to go for splits with `4GiB` size plus `128MiB` overlaps:

```
# first part:
dd if=/dev/external1 of=split.img bs=1M count=$((4096+128))
photorec split.img

# second part:
dd if=/dev/external1 of=split.img bs=1M skip=4096 count=$((4096+128))
photorec split.img
```

And in the next step you `skip=$((4096*2))` and so on... until you reach the end of the disk.

Comment: Thanks, but even though PhotoRec accepts the file, it stops searching after a few seconds. Any advice? I understand it may not increase speed that much, but at least would make the processing easier (I can't keep Photorec running forever).

Comment: Either it's so fast that it's done after a few seconds - entirely possible if your slice was small and empty - or you used the wrong settings. You want to `dd` a partition and make `photorec` search raw data w/o partitions.

Comment: Oh and I guess you might want to create a new directory for each slice, just in case `photorec` might be confused, try to resume, overwrite old files, ...

Comment: I tried again with a 20GB slice and it's working! The first time I tried with 1GB, which I thought would take a while, but was very fast. Thanks a lot!